# [Django]How to display a message(correct or incorrect) after submitting the form, without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, html, django, message

I have a made a quiz page, which checks whether the answer of the user is correct or not using a "checkans" function. I want to return a "Correct" message if the answer is correct and an "Incorrect" message if the answer is not correct. Now I can "kind of" do it, but not exactly what I want. Now it returns the message after redirecting to a whole new page, with the Question Box and everything else totally disappeared, only with the message.

I want the message to be shown on the same original question page, somewhere under the question box or within the question box, without redirecting to another page or refreshing the page, after submitting the answer. I don't know how to do it.

Here is my view:

```
class QuizView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'geniusdennis/quiz.html'
    queryset = Spanish.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # grab the max id in the database       
        max_id = Spanish.objects.order_by('-id')[0].id
        random_id = random.randint(1, max_id + 1)
        random_spanish_question = Spanish.objects.filter(id__gte=random_id)[0]
        context['random_spanish_question'] = random_spanish_question
        return context
```

Here is my function for checking the answer:

```
def checkans(request, spanish_id):
    random_spanish_question = get_object_or_404(Spanish, pk=spanish_id)
    query = request.GET.get('ans')
    coreng = random_spanish_question.english_set.get()
    if query == str(coreng):
        return render(request, 'geniusdennis/quiz.html',{
                'message': "Correct!",
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'geniusdennis/quiz.html', {
                'message': "Incorrect.",
                'correct_answer': "The correct answer is " + str(coreng),
            })
```

And here is my HTML page:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'geniusdennis/style.css' %}">

{% if random_spanish_question %}
<div class="flexcontainer" style="justify-content: center;">
    <div class="sectiontitle">Quiz time
    </div>
        <div class="question_card">
            <div class="question_word">{{ random_spanish_question }}</div>
            <form action="/checkans/{{random_spanish_question.id}}/" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
                <label for="ans">Answer:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ans"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Skip"/>

        </div>
</div>
{% else %}
{% if message %}
        <div class="message">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        <div class="ans">
            {{ correct_answer }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `ajax`, so you need some `js` code here.

```
<scrip src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('form').on('submit', function(e) { // or you can get the form by id if you set it

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

var form = $(this);
var url = form.attr('action');

$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: url,
       data: form.serialize(), // serializes the forms elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           ... // whatever you want to do
           var alertMessage = data.message;
           if (data.correct_answer) {
               alertMessage += ' ' + data.correct_answer;
           }
           alert(alertMessage); // show response
       }
     });
});
</script>
```

`html` forms will go to `action` url. If you want some changes or functions in your page without `reload`, you need to use `js`.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I've never used Ajax before, so I think I need some time to figure it all out. And I wonder whether Ajax is necessary? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know). When something requires `DOM` change (like adding to `html` some addings, deletions or changes in elements) I use `js`. So, because you are sending `request` to backend I thought `ajax` is proper solution. Maybe, you can look at @vishal-singh answer to find `Django` way solution. However, if you are using so much requests that requires frontend actions, I think adding `ajax` to your project would be a good solution)

Comment: After a bit of research, I think Ajax is the better way too. But I don't know how to work it out after using your code above...... it still goes to another page to show the "message" after I inserted your code. What else do I need to change?

Comment: @ProudHKer I've edited my answer, changed `.submit` to `.on('submit', ...)`

Comment: It still doesn't work... The `e.preventDefault()` is supposed to stop submitting the form and make the page stay, right? It goes to next page: [checkans/id/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=.............] right away. I am guessing the AJAX doesn't load at all. But I have no idea why.

Comment: Oh AJAX finally loads as I put it at the bottom of the body. I put it at the top. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Quite commonly in web applications, you need to display a one-time
>   notification message (also known as “flash message”) to the user after
>   processing a form or some other types of user input.
>
> For this, Django provides full support for cookie- and session-based
>   messaging, for both anonymous and authenticated users. The messages
>   framework allows you to temporarily store messages in one request and
>   retrieve them for display in a subsequent request (usually the next
>   one). Every message is tagged with a specific level that determines
>   its priority (e.g., info, warning, or error).

for implementing messages refer to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/